# Failed to open config file '/dev/fd/63', error: No such file or directory for wpa_supplicant

Tags: bash, arch-linux, sudo, wpa-supplicant, process-substitution

When I do this:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp4s0 -c <(wpa_passphrase "some ssid" "password")
```

I get

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Failed to open config file '/dev/fd/63', error: No such file or directory
Failed to read or parse configuration '/dev/fd/63'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_passphrase):

> Note: Because of the process substitution, you cannot run this command with sudo - you will need a root shell.

You should be able to use `su -c` under `sudo` like so:

```
$ sudo su -c 'wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp4s0 -c \
    <(wpa_passphrase "some ssid" "password")'
```

Answer (score 19):

[Process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) `<(…)` creates a pipe, uses `/dev/fd` to give a path that's equivalent to the file descriptor where the pipe is, and passes the file name as an argument to the program. Here the program is `sudo`, and it passes that argument (which is just a string, as far as it's concerned) to `wpa_supplicant`, which treats it as a file name.

The problem is that sudo closes all file descriptors except for the standard ones (stdin=0, stdout=1 and stderr=2). The pipe of the process substitution is on another descriptor, which gets closed, so when `wpa_supplicant` tries to open it, it finds a file that doesn't exist.

If your sudo policy allows it (`closefrom_override` option enabled), you can tell it not to close file descriptors. But this is usually not the case.

```
sudo -C 64 wpa_supplicant … -c <(wpa_passphrase …)
```

Alternatively, since you aren't using standard input, pass the data there.

```
wpa_passphrase … | sudo wpa_supplicant … -c /dev/stdin
```

Alternatively, run a shell from sudo and put the process substitution there. Take care with quoting if the command contains special characters.

```
sudo bash -c 'wpa_supplication … -c <(wpa_passphrase …)'
```

Comment: A little note: Both solutions are not 100% equivalent. The differ as in which user executes the password retrieving command.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from a web search engine: make sure your `/dev` is mounted. An easy mistake to make when chrooting, which can then result in errors such as this one.