# bash syntax - wrapping command inside sudo :: tail logs until string found with timeout using Terraform

Tags: grep, sudo, tail, timeout, subshell

**Goal:** using sudo execute a one line cmd to tail a log until a string is found and then exit 0.  If the string is not found within a given timeout, exit anything but 0.

**Attempted Solution 1:** Originally I did not have timeout as a requirement and so after some research I landed on using:

```
sudo sh -c '( tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log & ) | grep -q "Started .*Application"'
```

However, now I do have timeout as a requirement.  I could not figure out how to get timeout to work with this command until I found [Ondra Žižka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456103/6020034).  So my new cmd became:

**Attempt Solution 2:**

`timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)`

But this obviously is not using sudo permissions, which is the current issue I need to solve.  Below are some variations I've tried which failed

**Try 1 :** (add sudo in front of cmd)

```
sudo timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)
```

**Output:**

```
grep: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
```

**Try 2:** (try to wrap cmd in subshell)

```
sudo sh -c 'timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'
```

**Output:**

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Can someone show me and explain the issue and how to fix it so I can run this command using sudo?  Also, do I really need to restructure cmd from **Attempted Solution 1** to get it to work with timeout as well?

Comment: In Attempt Solution 2, Try 2: `sh` might point to `dash` or `bash` in POSIX mode, either way you won't be able to use process substitution `<(…)`.

Comment: @phk it is Ubuntu so it's using dash it looks like.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [Alexander Batischev's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279546/194729) to use `sudo su -c`.

**Solution (OLD):**

```
sudo su -c 'timeout 200 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on [ilkkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317653/194729) I did some more testing and found a new solution.

1. First, in response to *ilkkachu's* answer about `sudo su` being redundant. If I remove `sudo` from the command I'm prompted to enter a password.
2. Second, in response to *ilkkachu's* answer about a subshell not being useful. This is true.  However, the command without the subshell only returns if the log is actively being written to for some reason. Otherwise it hangs. When using the subshell the cmd returns even if the log is not actively being written to.  So I prefer subshell command, but `sh` doesn't support subshells.

   Also, I noticed when testing on an active log that the use of using `bash` vs. `sh` has different time. For some reason `sh` takes a second longer to respond then `bash`.

   For these two reasons (using subshell and delay in `sh` over `bash`) I decided `sh` is not suitable solution.
3. Third, in response to *ilkkachu's* answer regarding the unecessary & for `tail`.  That is correct, I removed it and it had no impact.

**Summary:**

**sudo su vs. su**

```
//prompts for password w/out sudo
su -c 'timeout 200 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n100 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)''

//works
sudo su -c 'timeout 200 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n100 -f  /path/to/nameOfLog.log  &)'
```

**using sh -c**

```
//either works (sudo or not using sudo)
//but both won't work unless log is actively being written to for some reason    

sudo sh -c 'tail -n100 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log | grep -q "Started .*Application"'

sh -c 'tail -n100 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log | grep -q "Started .*Application"'
```

**using bash**

```
//either works (sudo or not using sudo)

sudo bash -c 'timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n100 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'

bash -c 'timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n100 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'
```

**NEW Solution:**

I realized I left out one *important* detail. Which is that this was being executed via a [terraform remote-exec provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html).  Terraform creates a local .sh script under /tmp/ on the server for any [inline](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html#inline) commands.  The [communicator/ssh/communicator.go](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/communicator/ssh/communicator.go#L27) sets `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the scripts which means they are using `sh`.  So since I'm using a subshell I need to use bash.  The use of sudo is not necessary and was my misunderstanding.  However, you can still use sudo.  So the answer I went with is either of the **using bash** commands listed under the Summary above.

**P.S.** my target servers in this case were running *14.04.1-Ubuntu*.  Running `ls -l /bin/sh` shows `/bin/sh -> dash` so actually I'm not using `sh` but dash. So it appears `dash` has the same setbacks as `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure if the subshell (or backgrounding) is useful here:

```
sudo sh -c '( tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log & ) | grep -q "Started .*Application"'
```

shouldn't a simple pipe do?

```
sudo sh -c 'tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log | grep -q "Started .*Application"'
```

---

2) Your "try 1":

```
sudo timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)
```

expands the input redirection `<()` on the command line that runs the `sudo`, not inside `sudo`. The filehandle it opens isn't passed through `sudo` to `grep`, so `grep` can't open the `/dev/fd/63` pseudo-file.

Same thing about backgrounding the `tail` here, it shouldn't be necessary.

---

3) And, as [phk commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317555/bash-syntax-wrapping-command-inside-sudo-tail-logs-until-string-found-with#comment558141_317555), your "try 2":

```
sudo sh -c 'timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'
```

...explicitly runs `sh`, and not `bash` or any other more featureful shell. Plain standard `sh` doesn't support `<()`, and neither does `dash` which is used as `sh` on Debian and Ubuntu.

When you run `su` instead, it runs `root`'s login shell, which is likely to be `bash` on Ubuntu. But using both `sudo` and `su` is redundant, they're both made to elevate privileges, and after `sudo` *you're already running elevated privilege*, so no need for `su`. Instead, if you want to run a shell inside `sudo`, just say explicitly which one:

```
sudo bash -c 'timeout 5 grep -q "Started .*Application" <(tail -n1 -f /path/to/nameOfLog.log &)'
```

Comment: thanks for your help @ilkkachu it lead me to a better answer and understanding of how it works.  I've updated my answer.